# Moving Average using R code

Tags: r

The first part I need to have R code is about:

> Write an R function that does the following: Given a sequence xN = (x1; x2; ...; xN) of N
>       observations, the function returns a vector of moving averages, where each average is computed
>       with k consecutive observations. Name the function ma, and its arguments are the
>       vector xN and k.

What I have so far:

```
x <-vector(length=n)

ma <- function(x,k){
x0 <- x[1:(length(x)-k)]
x1 <- x[(1+k):length(x)]
cor(x0, x1)
}
```

I'm pretty sure that I made mistakes...

Comment: I'm wondering why you're using correlation when your homework assignment says to calculate the moving **average**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are loads of ways of calculating moving averages.

in base r, this can work

```
filter(x, rep(1/2,2)) #this calculates moving average of 2 numbers in a sequence
filter(x, rep(1/3,3))  #this calculates moving average of 3 numbers in a sequence
```

for k consecutive observations

```
filter(x, rep(1/k,k))
```

e.g.

```
x <- c(3,5,7,3,4,2,6,4,7,2,1,9, 1, 10, 1,12)
filter(x, rep(1/2,2))
# [1] 4.0 6.0 5.0 3.5 3.0 4.0 5.0 5.5 4.5 1.5 5.0 5.0 5.5 5.5 6.5  NA
```

You should also look up the following packages:  `zoo` and `TTR` packages for more options

Just as a quick example, the function `runMean` in TTR is super easy

```
runMean(x,2) #gives rolling mean of every 2 consecutive observations
runMean(x,k) #gives rolling mean of every k consecutive observations
```

Comment: I haven't learned filter, zoo, or rollmean, so maybe I should avoid use them.

Comment: @Keris So basically you just want your homework assignment fixed?

Comment: @RichardScriven No. What I'm saying is I want to know where I made mistakes. I didn't ask you to fix my hw assignment.

Comment: Fair enough.  The source code for `zoo:::rollmean.zoo` might help you in your calculations.

Comment: @jalapic Thank you so much. Btw, I need to find object 'k', will you give me a hint for this?

Comment: @jalapic I need to put 'k' value specifically right? Such as, y = ma(x,k=100)?

Comment: If for instance you're doing `runMean(x,k)` and k is e.g. 5, then you could write `runMean(x,5)` or `runMean(x,k=5)`.  Either are fine.   That logic should also apply to your ma function.